# Execute sql prepared statement with slice

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I've wrote an function (In Go, of course) that inserting `map[string]interface{}` to mysql via [this](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/) library.

### Explanation of the code below:

1. The functions receives `string` called *table* and `map[string]interface{}` called *data*.
2. I separate the `data` to keys (variable  called *columns*) and values (variable called *values*).
3. I generate from the *columns* variable called *column_text* that will look like this: `first_name, last_name, birth_day, date_added`
4. I generate from the *values* variable called *variable_text* that will look like this: `?, ?, ?, ?`
5. I open mysql connection: `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@/database")`
6. I create prepared statement: `stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO " + table + " ( " + columns_text + " ) VALUES ( " +  values_text + " )")`
7. I execute the prepare statement. but I have a problem. the number of the columns and values changes all the time, and the `stmt.Exec()` command can't receive an slice (Array) like this: `stmt.Exec(values)`, only the values alone like this: `stmt.Exec(values[0], values[1], values[2]...)`

### The question:

I'm coming from PHP, where PDO::Statement could receive an array when executing.
How can I execute the statement with the slice (Array)? (If I can do it with different library, please write the name of the library and how to use it, thank you!)

### The code:

```
func insertToDB(table string, data map[string]interface{}) {
columns := make([]interface{}, 0, len(data))
values := make([]interface{}, 0, len(data))

for  key, _ := range data {
   columns = append(columns, key)
   values = append(values, data[key])
}

columns_text := ""
i := 0
of := len(data)

for i < of {
    column := columns[i].(string)

    if i == 0 {
        columns_text = column
    } else {
        columns_text = columns_text + ", " + column
    }

    i++
}

fmt.Println(columns_text + " = " + table)

values_text := ""

i = 0

for i < of {

    if i == 0 {
        values_text = "?"
    } else {
        values_text = values_text + ", ?"
    }

    i++
}

fmt.Println(values_text)
fmt.Println(values)
fmt.Println(data)

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@/bacafe")
if err != nil {
    return -1, err
}
defer db.Close()

stmtIns, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO " + table + " ( " + columns_text + " ) VALUES ( " +  values_text + " )")
if err != nil {
    return -1, err
}
defer stmtIns.Close() // Close the statement when we leave main() / the program terminates

result, err := stmtIns.Exec(values...)
if err != nil {
    return -1, err
} else {
    insertedID, err := result.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    } else {
        return int(insertedID), nil
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT: I've edited the function above and it works perfectly now.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track however [`Stmt.Exec`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Stmt.Exec) takes `args ...interface{}`, so for your specific example you need to change 2 things:

```
......
values := make([]interface{}, 0, len(data))
......
//adding ... expands the values, think of it like func.apply(this, array-of-values) in 
// javascript, in a way.
_, err = stmtIns.Exec(values...)
```